# Web service client stacktrace

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

my intention is not to spam SO with my stacktraces, but i appreciate help help on this one

```
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
     faultSubcode: 
     faultString: Fault occurred while processing.
     faultActor: 
     faultNode: 
     faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Fault occurred while processing.
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at ch.skoutses.skoutsesten.webservices.contract.BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.getCourses(BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.java:287)
    at ch.skoutses.skoutsesten.common.service.contract.RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.getCourses(RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.java:62)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.controllers.BookCourseController.getAllCourses(BookCourseController.java:23)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.initComponents(CourseListFrame.java:60)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.start(CourseListFrame.java:37)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.Runner.main(Runner.java:9)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:usis-MacBook-Pro-15.local

Fault occurred while processing.
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at ch.skoutses.skoutsesten.webservices.contract.BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.getCourses(BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.java:287)
    at ch.skoutses.skoutsesten.common.service.contract.RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.getCourses(RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.java:62)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.controllers.BookCourseController.getAllCourses(BookCourseController.java:23)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.initComponents(CourseListFrame.java:60)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.start(CourseListFrame.java:37)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.Runner.main(Runner.java:9)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListTable.repaintTable(CourseListTable.java:28)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListTable.initTable(CourseListTable.java:22)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListTable.<init>(CourseListTable.java:14)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.initComponents(CourseListFrame.java:61)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.start(CourseListFrame.java:37)
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.Runner.main(Runner.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this relate to your problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.skoutses.bookcourse.gui.CourseListTable.repaintTable(CourseListTable.java:28)
```

Comment: Yes I see... I am trying to get the list of courses which should be returned frm database...i am passing the login parameters to connect to the system, but keep getting null...i actually dont know where to look at in these auto/generated stubs from eclipse. Probably overwhelming for me. Maybe some good tutorial on consuming the web service?